# Ошибка при установке пакета tonsdk

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

````
  Obtaining dependency information for tonsdk from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/23/493579f9ebcbaba54d7f220a2e062e936a54c661967eebe16b27cdbce612/tonsdk-1.0.13-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached tonsdk-1.0.13-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pynacl>=1.4.0 in e:\users\home-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tonsdk) (1.5.0)
Collecting bitarray==2.6.0 (from tonsdk)
  Using cached bitarray-2.6.0.tar.gz (102 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.4.1 in e:\users\home-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from pynacl>=1.4.0->tonsdk) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in e:\users\home-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->pynacl>=1.4.0->tonsdk) (2.21)
Using cached tonsdk-1.0.13-py3-none-any.whl (71 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: bitarray
  Building wheel for bitarray (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for bitarray (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\bitarray
      copying bitarray\test_bitarray.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\bitarray
      copying bitarray\test_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\bitarray
      copying bitarray\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\bitarray
      copying bitarray\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\bitarray
      copying bitarray\bitarray.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\bitarray
      copying bitarray\pythoncapi_compat.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\bitarray
      copying bitarray\test_data.pickle -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\bitarray
      copying bitarray\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\bitarray
      copying bitarray\util.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\bitarray
      copying bitarray\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\bitarray
      running build_ext
      building 'bitarray._bitarray' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for bitarray
Failed to build bitarray
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bitarray, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects```
````

Comment: Ну тут же английским языком написано: "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required."